# An inequality relates to a set of pairwise orthogonal unit vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality, orthonormal

**Question:**

> Let $\vec{u}_1, \dots, \vec{u}_k$ be pairwise orthogonal unit vectors
>   in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Prove that  $$ \vec{c}^\mathsf{T} \vec{c} \geq
>  \sum_{i=1}^k(\vec{c}^\mathsf{T} \vec{u}_i)^2 $$ for all $\vec{c} \in
>  \mathbb{R}^n$.

My attempt is the following:

Define $\vec{c} = [c_1 \dots c_n]^\mathsf{T}$and rewrite 
$$ 
\vec{c}^\mathsf{T} \vec{c} = \sum_{i=1}^n c_i^2
$$
Also, if $\vec{u}_1, \dots, \vec{u}_k$ are pairwise orthogonal unit vectors
in $\mathbb{R}^n$, we have $k \leq n$ (this seems to be true, but I don't know the reference). Therefore, to show the above inequality, it suffices to show that 
$$
c_i \geq \vec{c}^\mathsf{T} \vec{u}_i
$$
for all $i = 1, \dots, k$. I don't what should do next and how to apply the property of *pairwise orthogonal unit vectors*. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Verify that $\vec c^{T}\vec c-\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}(\vec c^{T} \vec u_i)^{2}=\|\vec c-\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \vec (c^{T} \vec u_i) u_i\|^{2}$ using the fact that $\|\vec y||^{2}=\vec y^{T} \vec y$.

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly, I got the answer from my graduate analysis course in the Hilbert spaces. The hint given by @Kabo Murphy is also well stated. For future readers, it is the [Bessel's inequality.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel%27s_inequality)